# Finding coordinates of a point from a frame in another frame in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, trigonometry

I have the normal, default x,y coordinate system. Lets call this **Frame1**.
I then use the following lines to create a new frame:

```
glTranslatef(40, 125, 0);
glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //theta is in degrees here
glTranslatef(-40, -125, 0);
```

Lets call this **Frame2**.

I have a point `(x,y)` in Frame2.
Now, how do I know the coordinates of the same point with respect to Frame1?
Meaning, the point remains stationary, but what is its coordinates with respect to Frame1?
I've tried:

```
alpha = atan2(Y,X);
hypo = Y/sin(alpha);
alphatheta = alpha + theta; //theta is in radians here and so is alpha
newY = hypo * sin(alphatheta);
newX = hypo * cos(alphatheta);
```

But this doesn't work. I guess there is some difference in Translation, due to the fact that the rotation was done around (40, 125) and not the origin.

So, how do I find out newX and newY ?
i.e. If I plot (newX,newY) in Frame1, I should get the same point as (X,Y) from Frame2.

Or, I could even ask it in this way,
If something is rotated around some point (a,b) by an angle theta, by how much would the same thing be rotated by, around the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by generating the matrices for each transformation and multiplying them with the point in Frame2. 
Let's say you have `(x, y, z, w)` in Frame2, `(X, Y, Z, W)` is its equivalent in Frame1 and you do following transforms to reach Frame2:

```
Frame1 -> Transform1 -> Transform2 -> Transform3 -> Frame2
(X, Y, Z, W) = Matrix(T1) x Matrix(T2) x Matrix(T3) x (x, y, z, w)
```

In your example, it will be:

```
(newX, newY) = T(40, 125, 0) x R(theta, 0, 0, 1) x T(-40, -125, 0) x (x, y)
```

Now, `T` and `R` are represented as row major matrices:

```
T(a, b, c) = { {0,0,0,a}, {0,0,0,b}, {0,0,0,c}, {0,0,0,1} }
R(a, 0, 0, 1) = { {cos(a),-sin(a),0,0}, {sin(a),cos(a),0,0}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1} }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..The importance of the order of multiplication cannot be stressed enough..